# YUV data in HEX to write into a YUV file

Tags: image-processing, video-capture, video-processing, yuv

I have a typedef structure containing the YUV components that I took from a video frame.

I need to find a way to write these YUV components into a (.YUV) file extension so I could use it for my application in C language.

Does anyone know, How can I can do it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Well, one of the more common yuv-formats (or rather YCbCr) is [YV12](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#YV12)

Its is also known as plane-separated 4:2:0 8bpp. Where the 4:2:0 denoted the subsampling used for the color components. 8bpp means the valid range is `[0-255]` (not realy true, but lets not go there right now...)

[image]

It consists of `width x height` bytes luma-samples (the Y-part) followed by `width x height / 4` Cb-data and the same amount of Cr-data. Total number of bytes for one frame is `width x height * 3 / 2`

So basically all you need to do is to write the Y-component as `uint8`, followed by Cb-data and Cr-data.

If you need some example code in c to look at, check my yuv-viewer on [github](https://github.com/figgis/yuv-viewer).
Hope it helps, if not, drop me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn how to write to a file in binary mode. Take a look at [these examples](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-binary-file-io). Once that is clear, all you need to do is dump the hex values of the YUV channels into file.